# How to get executable of C++ extension form setup.py not .so lib?

Tags: python, setup.py

As currently I am getting .so file when I make the build with disutils. I know there is a way but can someone narrow it down? Sorry If the question is too stupid. I am new to python build system. I want to run the output binary, which currently is a shared object.

Answer (score 0):

I have currently the same problem. I know that I can build an executable if I add this to the Extension constructor

```
Extension (...., 
    extra_link_args = ["-o./csolver/csolver"]
)
```

This builds an executable instead of the .so file. The problem is that the files are stored somewhere in the temp directory where the package is being prepared before moving to the target directory. What I'm currently trying to figure out how to change the destination to the place where I actually want the file to be at the end.